# Cron tabs cannot find proper Ruby version via Whenever gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, whenever

I wanted to set a cron tab which would execute a task located in my Rails app. In my config/schedule.rb:

```
every 2.minutes do
  #do something
end
```

Despite putting this task successfully into my cron jobs list it never gets executed. When I try to manually launch the script saved in my cron jobs list, that is:

/bin/bash -l -c 'cd /Users/me/Desktop/railsapp && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake reports:fetch --silent'

I get error about wrong Ruby version:

> Your Ruby version is 2.6.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.6.6

I use rbenv and both my local and global versions are set to 2.6.6. Furthermore version 2.6.3 is not even present on the list of available ones.

How can I change this version to proper one and make my cron jobs executable?

Comment: maybe 2.6.3 is the system's Ruby version? Like installed via your package manager?

Can you manually add the Rbenv init in the cronjob command: ``export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"; eval "$(rbenv init -)"; cd myApp && bundle exec ...``

Comment: Did you find a solution? Getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

I am getting same errors on Pro M1.
My app ruby version is 3.1.2, default MAC system verison is 2.6.8
I have add to `~/.bash_profile` file this content:

```
export RBENV_ROOT="${HOME}/.rbenv"

if [ -d "${RBENV_ROOT}" ]; then
  export PATH="${RBENV_ROOT}/bin:${PATH}"
  eval "$(rbenv init -)"
fi
```

And then run `. ~/.bash_profile`.

Add this line to `schedule.rb`: `env :PATH, ENV["PATH"]`
=> Don't forget update crontab with: `whenever --update-crontab --set environment='development'`

Crontab is working with rbenv.

Refs: https://blog.eq8.eu/article/cronntab-rbenv-bundle-exec-rake-task.html